# XMLHttpRequest return status 200 without connection in Firefox

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a function to detect if my App has a network connection or not. With IE11 and Chrome, the status change correctly when I stop the wireless. But with Firefox, I get always the status 200, with or without wireless. My function is:

```
private GetOffOnlineStatus(url: string, maxWaitTime: number, callback: (response: number) => void) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var noResponseTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        xhr.abort();
        if (callback) callback(xhr.status);
        return;
    }, maxWaitTime);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            clearTimeout(noResponseTimer);
            if (callback) callback(xhr.status);
        };
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

and I call this function in the constructor so (I found the url I use for my tests on this site: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/):

```
private urlCheckConn: string = "http://html5rocks-cors.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html";
private timeOutCheckConn: number = 1000;
private intervallCheckConn: number = 10000;

constructor() {

    //Call when the page is open
    setTimeout(this.GetOffOnlineStatus(this.urlCheckConn, this.intervallCheckConn, function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem("CurrentStatusConnection", response.toString());
        console.log(response.toString());
    }), 100);

    //Call every 10 seconds
    setInterval(() => {
        this.GetOffOnlineStatus(this.urlCheckConn, this.intervallCheckConn, function (response) {
            localStorage.setItem("CurrentStatusConnection", response.toString());
            console.log(response.toString());
        }); }, this.intervallCheckConn);
}
```

Apparently the reason is that the page is in the cache. It is possible to force the application to fetch always the file on the net? Or do I have to use another method? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine), both Chrome, Firefox and IE *(from 8 and up)* supports `navigator.onLine` ?

Comment: try adding a cache buster `urlCheckConn += '?cb=' + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

Comment: @naortor: Thank's, it work so!

Comment: @adeneo: The problem is that in chrome and safari (according [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)) a local network no connected to the Internet, return true. This is not acceptable for me.